# Split an invoice from total

Tags: c#, algorithm

So I have an Invoice, I converted it into dataset and it look like this:
[image: Datagridview image]

and I want to split it into different invoices (so i can have invoices that the total of them is the total of the original one) using total of quantity.

The program I am trying to code goes like this:

- The invoice total quantity is used to count the remaining quantity
- If the total quantity reach 0 then the job is done. if the total of the invoice greater that 5000.00 it should create new invoice the generated invoice should have the maximum product possible

Result should be like this:
invoice001 :
["Product01",27.00,5]
["Product02",40.00,5]

invoice002 :
["Product01",27.00,5]
["Product02",40.00,5]

The code is:

```
class Facture
{
    public int Fact_id  {get;set;}
    public float Total {get;set;}
    public List<Facture_line> Fac_line = new List<Facture_line>();
}
class Facture_line
{
    public String desc {get;set;}
    public float prix_unitaire { get; set; }
    public int quantite { get; set; }

}
```

I have also invoice list `Facture`

For demo I changed the limit 5000.00 to 500.00 but that not important, the process should work like this:

**1)**
InvoiceOrg = ["Product001",27,10]["Product002",40,10](total : 670)
Invoice[0] = ["Product001",27,0]["Product002",40,0] (total : 0)

**2)**
InvoiceOrg = ["Product001",27,9]["Product002",40,9](total : 603)
Invoice[0] = ["Product001",27,1]["Product002",40,1](total : 67)

**3)**
same as process 2)
InvoiceOrg = ["Product001",27,8]["Product002",40,8](total : 603)
Invoice[0] = ["Product001",27,2]["Product002",40,2](total : 134)

until the total of Invoice[0].Total >= 500.00f

and then  another Invoice["1"] is created and got filled the same way.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is quite confusing. How on earth did you get a total of 670 from `["Product001",27,10]["Product002",40,10]`?

Comment: What have you tried to solve that problem? Also, it would help if you use English names in your code. What do you mean by "*the generated invoice should have the maximum product possible*"? In the example, the maximum should be 7 items of each (and not 5 as you show).

Comment: let's say that we have an invoice and i want to split it,

Comment: i have  4 different products with different quantity, when i split the original  invoice i want to have the 4 product in all  in the generated invoice if possible but the sum of there quantity must  be the same as the the original invoice

Comment: some thing like this [link]( https://imgur.com/a/U6prhII)

Comment: i fixed the problem thanks for the help. and i did it all by myself like A BiG bOY

Answer (score -1):

I solved this Problem using **Excel Solver add ins** worked like charm.

It can help with 90% of this problem, the other 10% is to config it for your problems.

I didn't know it existed until now, so yeah I wasted one month of C# Coding of a function that already existed in Excel.

Comment: how do i apply someone else grammare fixes?